# Trouble retrieving values from Airtable database (Alexa Skill)

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, airtable

I am working on an Alexa Skill (ASK-SDK v.2 for Node.js) that executes a GET from an Airtable database. The user asks for a Character Name and the Skill checks it against this database to retrieve a brief description as a result.

However, when I do some testing on the Skill Builder, even if I say a Character Name that makes a ER_SUCCESS_MATCH in my JSON INPUT, the JSON OUTPUT returns the resolved value (any valid names, actually) as UNDEFINED. The message I hear back is "I can't find UNDEFINED in my database.", no matter the Character Name I inquire about.

I believe the Skill is failing to connect to my Airtable base to get a Character Name, even if I believe I provided the correct API key and AirtableGet key on my code. Moreover, I should be seeing a 'IN AIRTABLE GET' entry on my AWS Lambda Logs, right between the IN CHARACTER HANDLER and the usual END RequestID, but so far, I jump from IN CHARACTER HANDLER straight to END RequestID, so the Airtable db seems not invoked.

Here is the full Index.js code (minus the Skill number, the API Key and the Character Name column key). Can you spot any mistakes? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
const https = require('https');

const APP_ID = "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

const EmptyHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return false;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak()
                .reprompt()
                .getResponse();
    }
};

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log("IN LAUNCH REQUEST");
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak("Accessing the Skill. Say any name.")
            .reprompt("Go on, start.")
            .getResponse();
  },
};

const CharacterHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
               handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "CharacterIntent";
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log("IN CHARACTER HANDLER");

        var spokenValue = getSpokenValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, "character");
        var resolvedValues = getResolvedValues(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, "character");

        //NO MATCHES FOUND
        if (resolvedValues === undefined)
        {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                   .speak("I can't find " + spokenValue + " in my database." + getRandomQuestion())
                   .reprompt("" + spokenValue + " is not in my database. " + getRandomQuestion())
                   .getResponse();
        }
        //ONLY ONE MATCH FOUND
        else if (resolvedValues.length === 1)
        {
            var filter = "&filterByFormula=%7BName%7D%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(resolvedValues[0].value.name) + "%22";

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                airtableGet("appXXXXXXXXXX", "Character", filter, (record) => {
                    console.log("AIRTABLE RECORD = " + JSON.stringify(record));
                    var speechText = "Accessing to " + spokenValue + "<break time='.5s'/>" + record.records[0].fields.VoiceDescription;

                    console.log("RESPONSE BUILDER = " + JSON.stringify(handlerInput.responseBuilder));

                    resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder
                       .speak(speechText)
                       .reprompt(getRandomQuestion())
                       .getResponse());
                });
            });
        }
        //MORE THAN ONE MATCH FOUND.  DISAMBIGUATE.
        else if (resolvedValues.length > 1)
        {
            var valuesString = getValuesString(resolvedValues);

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                   .speak("You asked for " + spokenValue + ", but I have different matches for that name.  Do you mean " + valuesString + "?")
                   .reprompt("Do you want to talk about" + valuesString + "?")
                   .getResponse();
        }
  }
};

const HelpHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
               handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent";
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log("IN " +  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name.toUpperCase())
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak("I know a lot of things about these characters. Tell me something about them.")
                .reprompt("Go on.")
                .getResponse();
    }
};

const StopHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
               (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" ||
                handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent");
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log("IN " + handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name.toUpperCase())
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak("Okey. See you!")
                .getResponse();
    }
};

const SessionEndedHandler = { 
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
      console.log("IN SESSIONENDEDHANDLER");
              return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                  .speak(getRandomGoodbye())
                  .getResponse();
     }
  };

function getRandomQuestion()
{
    var questions = ["Say another name when you're ready.", "Tell me another    name.", "Say another one.", "Any other names?"];
    var random = getRandom(0, questions.length-1);
    return "<break time='.5s'/>" + questions[random]; 
}

function getRandom(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)+min);
}

function getSpokenValue(envelope, slotName)
{
    if (envelope &&
        envelope.request &&
        envelope.request.intent &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName] &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].value)
    {
        return envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].value;    
    }
    else return undefined;
}

function getResolvedValues(envelope, slotName)
{
    if (envelope &&
        envelope.request &&
        envelope.request.intent &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName] &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].resolutions &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0] &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values)
    {
        return envelope.request.intent.slots[slotName].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values;
    }
    else return undefined;
}

function getSlotName(envelope)
{
    if (envelope &&
        envelope.request &&
        envelope.request.intent &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[0] &&
        envelope.request.intent.slots[0].name)
    {
        return envelope.request.intent.slots[0].name;
    }
    else return undefined;
}

function getValuesString(values)
{
    var string = "";
    for (var i = 0;i<values.length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0) string += ", ";
        if (i === (values.length-1)) string += " or ";
        string += values[i].value.name;
    }
    return string;
}

function airtableGet(base, table, filter, callback) {
    console.log("IN AIRTABLE GET");
    console.log("BASE = " + base);
    console.log("TABLE = " + table);
    console.log("FILTER = " + filter);

    var options = {
        host: "api.airtable.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/v0/" + base + "/" + table + "?api_key=keyXXXXXXXXXX" + filter,
        method: 'GET',
    };

    console.log("PATH = https://" + options.host + options.path);

    var req = https.request(options, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var returnData = "";

        res.on('data', chunk => {
            returnData = returnData + chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            var data = JSON.parse(returnData);
            console.log("DATA = " + JSON.stringify(data));
            callback(data);
        });
    });
    req.end();
}

const RequestLog = {
    process(handlerInput) {
        console.log("REQUEST ENVELOPE = " + JSON.stringify(handlerInput.requestEnvelope));    
        return;
    }
};

const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log("Error handled: " + JSON.stringify(error.message));
        console.log('handlerInput:' + JSON.stringify(handlerInput));
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak('I am sorry, something went wrong on my side.')
            .getResponse();
  },
};

exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard() 
.addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    CharacterHandler,
    HelpHandler,
    StopHandler,
    SessionEndedHandler    
  )
.addRequestInterceptors(RequestLog)
.addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
.lambda();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What debugging have you tried so far? What happens if you just connect to the table and read a couple of rows? You have a lot of code, it would be easier for the community to help you if you could cut it down to the minimum that shows the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Review the code base on Jeff Blackenburg open sourced project, It heavily relies on AirTable https://github.com/jeffblankenburg/Unofficial_Star_Wars/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js. also, It might not hurt when you are making the call to Airtable through your Character function to isolate this as a separate program first, just to be sure it is actually calling your Table and returning data.